# Storm: get input fields in prepare()

Tags: java, apache-storm

Actually, this question comes from my programming thoughts:
in `fieldsGrouping()`, the input fields with same values will go to the same task of the bolt. Is it possible to get the value of the input fields during `prepare()` or before `execute()`?

Actually, I want to assign a unique id for the task no matter the same topology restarts.

Comment: I don't think this is possible... I also don't understand how the set of key values that are processed on a single task relates to assigning a unique task ID? Are you aware the Storm assigns task ID itself -- however, those might not be the same if you stop and re-start you topology? Why do you need those static task IDs? Maybe you achieve your goal without them.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I want to save the state of each task no matter in zookeeper or redis for recovery of state when the topology restarts. I know I can achieve this in execute(). However, I think recovery the state in prepare() is graceful.

Comment: I guess this might be difficult. Did you have a look into Trident? It can handle state for you too (so you don't have to implement is by yourself).

Comment: Thanks, I will learn Trident.

Answer (score 1):

If it's that important for you to know which tasks handle which values, you might take a look at directed streams for which you emit not only the tuple and stream id, but also the task id of the component instance to handle the tuple.  You're basically implementing fields grouping by yourself.  That's a bit more work, but at least you know in the prepare() what values go where because it's your logic that determines that.

Comment: You mean the task id can be assigned before the task starts using directed streams?

Comment: The task ID's are assigned to component instances by Storm, but that happens before the prepare().  You just need to think in terms of instances 1...n and let Storm tell you what those task ID's are (via the topology context passed into prepare()).